# How to pass a parameter when rendering an R script with spin?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr-spin

I'm creating an HTML output from a .R script with the command `rmarkdown::render(input = "my_script.R")`. It calls `knitr::spin()` and successfully produces an HTML output.  In that .R file, there is a filtering variable `school_level` whose value I want to control from the call to `render()`.

I know for an RMarkdown file I'd specify a parameter in the YAML header.  But how do I do that for a .R script?  I'm not seeing it in guides like the [RMarkdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/spin.html).

Say the line I want to modify in my .R script is:

```
good_data <- my_data %>%
  filter(level == school_lvl)
```

What do I change in my .R script to control the value of `school_lvl` from the call to `rmarkdown::render`?  Making the value of `school_lvl` be "Elementary" or "Secondary".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass some parameters from the `params` argument of [`rmarkdown::render()`](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/docs/reference/render.html) function to `knitr`, it's a bit complicated as the `knitr::spin()` function overrides parameters. You can specify a commented header in your R script (as seen in the [documentation](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_report_from_r_script.html)), with empty parameter value, e.g. `test.R`:

```
#' ---
#' params:
#'   wanted_cyl: null
#' ---

library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
 filter(cyl == params$wanted_cyl)
```

Then you can call:

```
rmarkdown::render(input = "test.R", params = list("wanted_cyl" = 6))
```

Comment: This is a great minimal example, thanks.  It worked in this test example and then not in my .R script, and was enough for me to isolate my underlying problem: the previous author of this script started with `rm(list = ls())` which was erasing the parameter!